# Getting to testing site when typing dev.example.de (subdomain for testing basically)

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I want to get directed to my testing site when I type dev.example.de. The directory already exists, but everytime I type dev. I get directed to the production page (without dev). I've been trying to adjust my htaccess files for hours, but to no avail.

My Htaccess file in my root html folder looks like this:

```
<strike>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.de
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.de/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]


# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

My htaccess file inside the dev folder of my developer directory looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=dev.example.de
RewriteRule (.*) https://dev.example.de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

My domain and subdomain are both hosted on the same server.

Comment: Configure a [new vhost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html).

Comment: Is that necessary because I only have one IP adress? We have our own server with one IP where the * and dev are set.

Comment: The point of vhosts is to differ based on the name. It's the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Alright, thank you!

Comment: But the site will be only accessible from the machine the vhost is running or right? We want that everyone with that link can reach that site. Is that way harder to do?

Comment: I gave you a link to the documentation for Apache. Read it. If you don't understand the underlying concepts of how to configure your webserver, this site is probably not for you.